# Regex to extract till colon followed by a number

Tags: regex

I am attempting to write regex to extract fields from the following string:

```
String str = "www.com::part1::part2:1363737603029:1472164||";
```

I need to extract till the ":" after part2, i.e, till colon is followed by a number. As you can see the : character appears in double in previous places, so if I write [^:] then it stops after www.com. I tried [^(:\d+)] and that also didn't work. Please help me out.

Thanks,

keerthana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String str = "www.com::part1::part2:1363737603029:1472164||";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(.*?\\:)(?=\\d)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
www.com::part1::part2:
```

Answer (score 1):

`/^(.*?):[0-9]/`

Explanation:

```
^ start from the beginning
(.*?) match anything, non-greedily (and capture)
: match a colon
[0-9] match a digit
```

I've assumed perl-compatible regex, for the non-greedy matching.

Comment: Hi Chris,Thanks for your response. I am using python-flavoured regex and I want to be able to extract www.com::part1::part2 as a separate field.

Comment: Then if you use something like `m = re.search('^(.*?):[0-9]', 'www.com::part1::part2:1363737603029:1472164||')` then `m.group(0)` should contain your extracted field.

Answer (score 0):

it's necessary regex?? or you can use a java class?
like:

```
StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(str, ":");


    while (st2.hasMoreElements()) {
        System.out.println(st2.nextElement());
    }
```